# Generate Makefile using GYP on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, makefile, automake, gyp

What do I need to do to get GYP to generate your typical unix-like makefile stack for Mac OS X?

I currently get it to generate XCode build projects using the following config file:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "hello",
      'type': 'executable',
      "sources": [ "hello.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and then run the following at the CLI:

`gyp --depth binding.gyp`

This generates a directory: `binding.xcodeproj` which contains the XCode project.

I rather want your standard unix-like make build for OSX. Also, I'm going to want to import this project to Windows, which I'll want to use the MS compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. Quite simple, really. Thank you to TooTallNate. I was getting an error the way I was originally doing it. You do it explicitly like so:

`gyp --depth=./ binding.gyp --format=make`